# How to use the picture takes from camera?

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that i want to take the picture from camera.For that i used the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera.But my problem is how to get that image intomy application.Please tell me how to manage that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats pretty simple. You have a method in `UIImagePickerController` which is 
`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImageWithMediaInfo(NSDictionary *)info`. You can get here the image user had selected from `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`. Now declare an object of `UIImage` in the header of your AppDelegate. For example I declare `UIImage *pickedImage`. The purpose to declare this in AppDelegate is that we can use this Image anywhere in our app. Dont retain and synthesize this object. Now come back to your `didFinishPickingImage` method and now your body of this method should look like this:

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {`

`((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).pickedImage= [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`

`}`

Now you can easily use this image all over your app by just calling `((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).pickedImage`. Hope it helps.

Happy Coding!